# Discord bot not taking input

Tags: discord.js, bots

using Node.js (v16.11.1) and latest discord.js at time of post.
trying to get simple reply.
When bot is running, the '/ping' works and it asks me 'why did you ping me?', but then times out 15 seconds later no matter what input I give it, printing 'You did not enter any input!'.

What am i doing wrong?  Please help.

```
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const { commandName } = interaction;

    if (commandName === 'ping') {
        await interaction.reply('Why did you ping me?').then(() => {
       // const filter = m => m.content.startsWith('!test');
       const filter = m => interaction.user.id === m.author.id;
        
        interaction.channel.awaitMessages({ filter, time: 15000, max: 1, errors: ['time'] })
        .then(messages => {
            interaction.followUp(`You've entered: ${messages.first().content}`);
        })
        .catch(() => {
            interaction.followUp('You did not enter any input!');
        });
        
        
        });
    } 
});
```

Comment: Try logging the error (instead of `.catch(() => {})` do `.catch(console.log)`

Comment: @MrMythical the console prints:
```Collection(0) [Map] {}```